# list indices must be integers not str ( easy answer probably)

Tags: python

I recently asked a question about the high scores issue on a previous post.  This is a class project so it should be relatively simple. I am still new to this website so I am unsure how to cleanly post new revisions so if you have read part of this I apologize.  This time I am just going to put the entire program here.  Everything works except the high scores part.  When I select to just check the high scores list before playing the game the output works nicely, however, after playing the game, returning to the main menu and then checking high scores again I get the error that

> list indices must be integers not str

.  I assume that means my original scores list is set up incorrectly but I'm not entirely sure.  Here is the code and I truly appreciate the help.  This site is fantastic for such.

```
import random
loop_game = True

while loop_game:
    questions= [
                {"question": "Who won the 2012 NFL Superbowl?",
                 "answers": ["Jacksonville Jaguars",
                            "Oakland Raiders",
                            "New York Giants",
                            "Baltimore Ravens"],
                 "correct": "4"},
                {"question": "Which song was at the top of the charts in early 2001, by OutKast?",
                 "answers": ["Bootylicious",
                             "Angel",
                             "Ms. Jackson",
                             "U Got It Bad"],
                "correct": "3"},
                {"question": "How many centimeters are one inch?",
                 "answers": ["2.12",
                             "2.54",
                             "3.24",
                             "3.38"],
                "correct": "2"}]

    scores=[{'initials': None,
             'score': -500}]

#main menu
    def main_menu():
        global loop_game
        print("""
***********************************************  
Welcome to The Greatest Trivia Show on Earth!!!
***********************************************
1. Play Game
2. High Scores
3. Credits
4. Instuctions
5. Quit
""")
        needs_input = True
        while needs_input:
          selection = input("Which Selection would you like? ")
          if selection == "1":
              play_game()
              needs_input = False
          elif selection == "2":
              display_scores()
              needs_input = False
          elif selection == "3":
              credits()
              needs_input = False
          elif selection == "4":
              instructions()
              needs_input == False
          elif selection == "5":
              needs_input = False
              loop_game = False
          else:
              print("\nSelect a valid option\n")

    def play_game():
        #definitions
        global total_points
        global questions
        loop_pa = True
        total_points = 3
        random.shuffle(questions)
        counter = 0
        #gets name in case of high score
        global hs_name
        hs_name = input("What are your initials?: ")


        #main play loop
        while counter < 2:
            for j in questions:
                counter += 1
                print("\n",j["question"])
                for i, choice in enumerate(j["answers"]):
                    print(str(i+1) + ". " + choice)
                answer = str(input("\nChoose an answer 1-4: "))
                if answer == j["correct"]:
                    print("\nGood job! You keep your precious points...this time!\n")
                else:
                    print("\nSorry, that is not correct. You lose one point.\n")
                    total_points -= 1
                    print("\nTotal Points: ",  total_points)

        #all questions have been read
        print("\nThat's it, your score is: ", total_points)

        #check/append best scores list
        best_scores()

        #keep playing loop
        while loop_pa:
            keep_playing = input("Play again?  (y, n) \n")
            if keep_playing == "y":
                print("\nAwesome! Here we go! \n\n")
                loop_pa = False
                play_game()
            elif keep_playing == "n":
                print("Ahh, too bad.  Thanks for playing!")
                loop_pa = False
                main_menu()
            else:
                print("Select a valid option\n")

    def best_scores():
        for i, score in enumerate(scores):
            if total_points > score['score']:
                scores[i:i+1] = {'initials': hs_name, 'score': total_points}
                del scores[5:]
                break

    def display_scores():
        print("HIGH\tSCORES")
        for score in scores:
            print(score['initials'], "\t", score['score'])

    def instructions():
        print("""

*************
Instructions
*************
The game is quite simple:  You start out with 12 points.
You lose a point for every incorrect answer.
If you get an answer correct, your score stays the same
and you move forward through the question set.  Try to
see how many points you can keep!
         """)
        main_menu()

    def credits():
        print("\nCreated by Jessica Gregg and Jason Vignochi\n")
        main_menu()


    main_menu()
```

## edit: oh! The line the error is at is in the display_scores function at (line 119)

> print(score['initials'], "\t", score['score'])

Comment: To start off with, your questions list only has one item, so shuffling it won't do you any good; and can you explain what is going on with this `del scores[5:]`.

Comment: shuffling it just randomizes the order in which the questions are asked and it seems to be ok.  The del scores[5:] is just supposed to cut the list off after five scores so I don't have an infinite list of high scores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are messing up your `scores` with `best_scores()`.  After the first time through it looks like `['score', 'initials']`. The slice assignment expects an iterable, and sure enough a dict iterates over its keys when used as an iterable. Try this, looks a little simpler (though I would probably just append and sort):

```
def best_scores():
    global scores
    for i, score in enumerate(scores):
        if total_points > score['score']:
            scores.insert(i, {'initials': hs_name, 'score': total_points})
            scores = scores[:5]
            break
```

my way:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def best_scores():
    global scores
    scores.append({'initials': hs_name, 'score': total_points})
    scores = sorted(scores, key=itemgetter('score'), reverse=True)[:5]
```

Comment: Awesome, the insert worked but the only issue now is that I keep overwriting the previous score rather than appending to the list. but list.append() only allows one argument so I'm not really sure how to approach that

Comment: @JasonVignochi are you sure you are using `list.insert` ? It works for me.  But I included my way, since I like it better ;-)

Comment: I was definitely using insert...hmm...I also tried your way as well because I too like that better however now I get the error File "C:/Users/PBR For Lunch/Desktop/Python scripts/test.py", line 113, in best_scores
    scores = sorted(scores)[:5]
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < dict()

Comment: @JasonVignochi make sure to use the key, so the dict can be sorted

Comment: @JasonVignochi I see it now, you are reseting your `scores` each time though the `loop_game`. so if you play several games they all show up, but if you go back to main menu and then play again, it resets.

Comment: HIGH SCORES
    jrv   3
    jrv   3
    jrv   3
    jrv   3   Is what I get when I play through three times with three separate initials and 3 different scores without returning to the main menu.  Sorry for my sloppy comments I'm still trying to figure this out and thanks for the help I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JasonVignochi you have 2 ways to play another game.  After the game it will ask you if you want to play again (staying in the game function).  Or if you go back to the main menu you can select `1` and play the game again that way.  If you go back to the main menu it will reset your `scores` because the the second thing the main menu loop does is `scores=[{'initials': None, 'score': -500}]`  This should probably be done before the loops, since you only want to initialize it once.

Comment: @JasonVignochi when I play without going back to the main menu, I get different scores and initials. Wonder if this is because you are using python3 and calling it recursively.  You can loop in play_game without calling it self again. Also you dont need the name to be a global, you should probably just be passing it to highscore.

Comment: Wow thanks so much. I moved the original list outside of the while loops and noticed that I wasn't referencing the indices of my list properly in the display_list function, I was just printing out the 0 index of the list for every item in the list.  You have been a huge help.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line:

```
scores[i:i+1] = {'initials': hs_name, 'score': total_points}
```

When you replacing a subslice of a sequence, you have to replace it with another iterable. For example:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a[2:3] = [3] # fine
>>> a[2] = 3 # fine
>>> a[2:3] = 3
TypeError: can only assign an iterable
```

So, why isn't your code a `TypeError`? Because a `dict` actually *is* an iterable—it acts like a list of its keys. So, when you try to replace the sub-list `[{'initials': old_name, 'score': old_score}]` with the dictionary `{'initials': new_initials, 'score': new_score}`, what it actually sees is, effectively, `['initials', 'score']`.

So, later on, when you get down to trying to print out the scores, one of them isn't a `dict`, it's the string `'initials'`. And you're trying to use that as a `dict`, hence the error.

You can see this more easily if you `print(scores)` before and after calling `best_scores`, and print out each `score` in `display_scores`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I understand what you are referring to now.  This was a huge help.

Answer (score -1):

You defined `scores` as a list of a list by using `[{}]`, so to reference it as it appears you want to, use `scores[ 0 ][ 'initial' ]`, etc.

Comment: `[{}]` is a list of a dict, not a list of a list. Also, `scores[0]['initial']` is the same thing as `score['initial']` after `for score in scores:`. And adding a bunch of extra non-PEP8-compliant spaces doesn't change any of that.